# Manipulação de ping em Python

Tags: python

estou criando um código que da um ping em uma lista de ips. Eu consegui fazer ele pingar e me dar a resposta, mas não consigo fazer a condição que desejo, que é:

```
SE ping ok:
   continuar os comandos
SENÃO:
   faz outra coisa.
```

Não sei como manipular a resposta do ping para colocar esta lógica no código, podem me ajudar?

Desculpe, sou iniciante.

Este é meu código:

```
#coding: utf-8
import sys
import os
import platform
import subprocess
from ips_list import radius

plat = platform.system()
scriptDir = sys.path[0]
if plat == "Windows":
    for ip in radius:
        try:
            line = ip.strip()
            ping = subprocess.Popen(
                ["ping", "-n", "2", "-l", "1", "-w", "100", line],
                stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr = subprocess.PIPE
            )
        expect:


if plat == "Linux":
    for ip in radius:
        line = ip.strip( )
        ping = subprocess.Popen(
            ["ping", "-c", "1", "-l", "1", "-s", "1", "-W", "1", line],
            stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr = subprocess.PIPE
        )
        out, error = ping.communicate()
        print out
        print error
```

Como posso adicionar esta lógica do if.. else nele?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza esta [função](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32684938/1778483), funciona em linux e windows, para python 2.7 ou 3:

```
def ping(host):
    import os, platform

    if  platform.system().lower()=="windows":
        ping_str = "-n 1"
    else:
        ping_str = "-c 1"

    resposta = os.system("ping " + ping_str + " " + host)
    return resposta == 0
```

A função devolve verdadeiro se o ping obtiver resposta e falso em caso de insucesso.

Answer (score 0):

eu fiz dessa forma, pegando através de uma lista de IPS e fazendo um loop infinito para verificar cada um:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess
import os
import time
ips = ['192.168.0.8','192.168.0.11','192.168.0.12','192.168.0.13','192.168.0.18']

while True:
    with open(os.devnull, "wb") as limbo:
        for ip in ips:

            result=subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c", "1", "-n", "-W", "2", ip],
                    stdout=limbo, stderr=limbo).wait()
            if result:
                    print ip, "inativo"
            else:
                    print ip, "ativo"

    time.sleep(2)
    print(' -- recomeçar --')
```

Answer (score -4):

Agradeço pelo post de vocês e gostaria de por minha contribuição

```
import subprocess
import os
import time
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

ips = ['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.100', '10.0.0.110', '10.0.0.111', '10.0.0.112', '10.0.0.113', '10.0.0.116']


def check_ips():
    for ip in ips:
        try:
            result = subprocess.check_output(["ping", "-n", "3", "-w", "3", ip])
            ip_status[ip] = "ativo"
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            ip_status[ip] = "inativo"

    update_dashboard()

    root.after(5000, check_ips)  # Executar a cada 5 segundos


def update_dashboard():
    for ip, status in ip_status.items():
        label = ip_labels[ip]
        label.config(text=f"{ip}: {status}")

    plot_graph()


def plot_graph():
    plt.clf()
    statuses = list(ip_status.values())
    plt.bar(ips, statuses, color=['green' if status == 'ativo' else 'red' for status in statuses])
    plt.xlabel('IPs')
    plt.ylabel('Status')
    plt.title('Status dos IPs')
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(plt.gcf(), master=frame)
    canvas_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
    canvas_widget.pack()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Exemplo")

ip_status = {}
ip_labels = {}

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

for ip in ips:
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=f"{ip}: Verificando...", padx=10)
    label.pack()
    ip_labels[ip] = label
    ip_status[ip] = "Verificando..."

check_ips()

root.mainloop()
```